# Как работают сигналы в python?

Tags: python, signal

Помогите разобраться с сигналами в python. Не могу найти статью с доступным обозначением и принципом работы.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html

Comment: Если вопрос о PyQt5, то вот тут по русски понятно написано:
https://pythonworld.ru/gui/pyqt5-eventssignals.html

Comment: @Павел, `по-русски` пишется именно так :)

Comment: @0andriy извините если чем-то огорчил, в школе по этому предмету всегда получал 3. В силу возраста уже стараюсь писать без ошибок и по всем правилам, но иногда проскакивают косяки. Ради этого комментария поинтересовался, как пишется "чем-то".
Но позволю себе заметить, тут, вроде, вопрос не "как пишется", а "разобраться с сигналами в Python"?

Comment: @Павел, несмотря на сарказм, «чем-то» может писаться через дефис, если «то» добавляет к местоимению неопределённости, если же это два слова («этот Павел лучше, чем то, что о нём говорят»), тогда раздельно.